# Using Pandas DataFrame to Generate Trading Signals

Tags: python, pandas, quantitative-finance

I have two DataFrames with the following layouts:

QUOTES DataFrame

```
DATE          PRICE        SMA
2008-06-25    107.505122 106.480321
2008-06-26    107.138449 103.531552
2008-06-27    106.737588 102.608466
2008-06-30    106.360232 101.309296
2008-07-01    105.993987 101.941783
2008-07-02    105.632870 101.796483
```

SIGNALS DataFrame

```
DATE          LONG ENTRY LONG EXIT
2008-06-25    0          0
2008-06-26    0          1
2008-06-27    1          0
2008-06-30    0          1
2008-07-01    0          1
2008-07-02    1          0
```

The first DataFrame is stock prices and moving averages. The second DataFrame contains signals for when to purchase a stock (entry) and when to sell (exit).

The entry part is already ok. But i'm having problems with the exit part.

It would not make sense to have an exit signals on the `2008-06-26` because no stock has been purchased yet. And it would not make sense to have an exit signal on both `2008-06-30` and `2008-07-01` because we can't sell the same stocks twice.

So I have a way to generate signals in the `LONG EXIT` column, but I need to filter them by looking backwards from each date to figure out if the is a `LONG ENTRY = 1` earlier and no `LONG EXIT = 1` between the `LONG ENTRY = 1` and the `DATE` I'm looking at.

The DataFrame that I need looks like this, but how can I do that with Pandas?

SIGNALS DataFrame

```
DATE        LONG ENTRY LONG EXIT
2008-06-25           0         0
2008-06-26           0         0
2008-06-27           1         0
2008-06-30           0         1
2008-07-01           0         0
2008-07-02           1         0
```

Comment: I looks to me answer to your question goes beyond SO. Did you have a chance to read articles at quantstart.com, eg https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Backtesting-a-Moving-Average-Crossover-in-Python-with-pandas or this one by the same author https://s3.amazonaws.com/quantstart/media/powerpoint/an-introduction-to-backtesting.pdf?  All that material IS relevant in your context (notice I am not sponsored of whatsoever [unfortunately] by quantstart.com)

Comment: The question is not about anything quant related. It is only the context. The real problem is how to transform/filter the dataframe

Comment: I also recommend posting some example code of how you're generating the `DataFrame`. The context helps people provide better answers.

Comment: You have to track what is currently in your portfolio. Maybe you can create a specific dataframe or add a column 'holding' somehwere and test whether it is > 0 before spurring trading order (eg see slides 14 and 15 in the second link I provided above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sketch of how you could track the balance of your entry/exit signals so you only signal exit when there's a previous entry not yet canceled by subsequent exit:

Starting with:

```
        date  entry  exit
0 2008-06-25      0     0
1 2008-06-26      0     1
2 2008-06-27      1     0
3 2008-06-30      0     1
4 2008-07-01      0     1
5 2008-07-02      1     0
```

Add a `column` for your new, filtered signals:

```
df['filtered_exit'] = np.nan
```

Iterate through the `DataFrame`, calculate the prior balance (this assumes you'd not be signaling entry and exit for the same day), and filter accordingly:

```
for i, data in df.iterrows():
    holding_status = (df.loc[:(i-1), 'entry'] - df.loc[:(i-1), 'filtered_exit']).sum()
    if data.exit == 0 or i == 0:
        df.loc[i, 'filtered_exit'] = 0
    elif data.exit == 1:
        if holding_status == 0:
            df.loc[i, 'filtered_exit'] = 0
        elif holding_status == 1:
            df.loc[i, 'filtered_exit'] = 1
```

to get the desired result given the cases you mentioned:

```
        date  entry  exit  filtered_exit
0 2008-06-25      0     0              0
1 2008-06-26      0     1              0
2 2008-06-27      1     0              0
3 2008-06-30      0     1              1
4 2008-07-01      0     1              0
5 2008-07-02      1     0              0
```

Hope this helps.